# Did not get expect result- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

Why i can not get result (KFC is a American restaurant)? How can i change it ?Do i meet the requirement ?

```
class Restaurant:  
    __name=""
    __cuisine=""


    def __init__(self,name,cuisine):
        self.__name=name
        self.__cuisine=cuisine

    def describe_restaurant(self):
             print(self.__name,  " is a ",self.__cuisine ," restarurant.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
             print(self.__name ," is open.")


def test():
    p=Restaurant("KFC","American")
    print(p.describe_restaurant)
```

Comment: That's because `p` is defined in `t` so it's out of scope . You could pass it as an argument ( `h(p)` )

Comment: @t.m.adam has replied perfectly. If I may add, another response suggests global variables which are generally not considered best practice in any programming language. Further, based on the requirements for your code, it appears that you needn't have two separate functions at all. A single function 'test'' should adequately cater to the requirements mentioned in the attached document. Also, the call to print the return value of p.describe_restaurant will fail as describe_restaurant() has no return value. Merely call p.describe_restaurant().

Comment: I would not use print statements in `describe_restaurant` en `open_restaurant`, let it return a string.

Answer (score 1):

`describe_restaurant` is a function. When you write

```
print(p.describe_restaurant)
```

you're getting a string representation of a function. You, however, wanted to call this function, let it execute, and print its return value. To do that, call it by adding parentheses:

```
p.describe_restaurant()
```

In addition, make sure to actually call your `test` method, like this:

```
test()
```

Comment: thank you,  i modified it but it still does not work.

Comment: @TianxuZang Works fine for me, and [at ideone](http://ideone.com/Rkq6Pj) as well. Can you verify that you have exactly the [same code that's posted on ideone](http://ideone.com/Rkq6Pj)?

Comment: If this (or any other) answer solves your question, feel free to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!